# Python 3 game SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. 'Learn Python 3 The Hard Way'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working with the book "Learn Python 3 the hard way", and I've gotten stuck ina exercise where you are supposed to create a game.

I'm stuck with an error that says:

```
File "ex45.py", line 83
return 'death'
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.


from random import randint
from sys import exit
from textwrap import dedent


class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
            You enter a door
            and you are teleported to a whole nother world!
            """))


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

             current_scene.enter()


class Finished(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print("You won! Good job.")
        return 'finished'


class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You're dead puta!"
        "You died son."
        "God damn it, YOU SUCK!"
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print(Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)])
        exit(1)


class Angalania(Scene):
    print(dedent("""
        Welcome to 'Angalania', the world that is full of
        beautiful creatures and plants, but beware!
        There also alot of monsters!
        You will be entering several houses to seek your fortune
        OR YOUR PAIN!
        Godspeed!

        You're in the beautiful village of 'Andarino'
        where you have 2 choices either you enter garden #1 of the 
        young and beautiful woman who is tempting you with bear and 
        food, but wait on the other side there is another garden, not 
        beautiful but not ugly there is an old woman that is warning 
        you...'Do not enter young boy, come here instead.' That young 
        woman is a witch who has turned herself young so she can 
        tempt young boys like you and eat their flesh to stay 
        young...
        Choose between garden #1 or #2.
        """))

    choice = input('> ')

    if choice == '1' or choice == '#1':
        print(dedent("""
            Good choice young man, the young woman wasn't a witch
            she was a beautiful innocent princess who loves you
            til' death, and feeds you with food and beverage..
            """))
    elif choice == '2' or choice == '#2':
        print(dedent("""
            Stupid fuck!
            You should have trusted your instincts...
            The old woman was the witch...
            """))
        return 'death'

    else:
        print("DOES NOT COMPUTE!")
        return 'angalania'


class DieOrLive(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
        After you entered the true princesses garden,
        the old witch got jealous and sent her little devils to
        her house. 
        they took the princess and made you guess play a guessing 
        game underneath 3 cups, there is one ball.
        you have to choose the right cup between 1-3. You have 3 
        chances...
        Shuffling..........
        """))

        cup = f"{randint(1,3)}{randint(1,3)}{randint(1,3)}"
        guess = input("> ")
        guesses = 3

        while guess != cup and guesses < 3:
            print("WRONG!")
            guesses += 1
            guess = input("> ")

        if guess == cup:
            print(dedent("""
                Good Job! The princess is released and you get even 
                more food and beverage!
                """))
            return 'the_castle'
        else:
            print(dedent("""
                You choose the wrong answer for the third time!
                You hear 'AAAAAAAAAAH' and see the princess's head 
                roll down the stairs.
                Now the little devils turn their attention to you...
                """))
            return 'death'


class TheCastle(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
            You have entered the last scene!
            After the near-death experience
            you decided to end this bullshit
            and kill the old witch!
            At the castle there are 5 doors!
            Which one do you open?
            """))

    good_door = randint(1, 5)
    guess = input("[door #]> ")

    if int(guess) != good_door:
        print(dedent("""
            You enter the wrong room!
            It's full of snakes and you 
            get bitten and turn into a worm...
            """))
        return 'death'

    else:
        print(dedent("""
            Good Job! You have found the witch!
            And you slash and you slash and you slash,
            until there is nothing more to slash!
            Now you and the princess live forever happily,
            As Queen and King!
            """))
        return 'finished'


class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'angalania': Angalania(),
        'dieorlive': DieOrLive(),
        'thecastle': TheCastle(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
    }

    def __init(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map('angalania')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Comment: `elif choice == '2' or choice == '#2':...  return 'death'` is not in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Error gives you line numbers, so look at it, and use an editor that shows you indentation levels

1. `class Angalania` has no functions at all. And a few returns.
2. 

```
class TheCastle(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
            You have entered the last scene!
            After the near-death experience
            you decided to end this bullshit
            and kill the old witch!
            At the castle there are 5 doors!
            Which one do you open?
            """))

    #------- indentation here is outside of a function  ------
    good_door = randint(1, 5)
    guess = input("[door #]> ")
```

You then have an if statement and `return 'death'` that is not indented